# Python - Get max value of a column then print two different columns that relate to that max value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if the title is a bit incoherent.

This is all done in pandas and basically I have 20 columns but all I need for what I'm trying to do is the following three:

```
Area      Month      DetectedSpeed
Wendly      1              15
Wendly      1              35
Wendly      2              18
Sarall      6              23
```

I am trying to print the area and month of the highest speed (DetectedSpeed).
So my output should be: **Wendly 1 35**

I've gone through a dozen different posts and have tried multiple variations of code and I've gotten extremely close but I can't figure out how to link the columns in the way I'd like.

I tried df.groupby which I knew wasn't correct and also df.max() but I was getting a bunch of errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html?highlight=idxmax#pandas.Series.idxmax

> Return the row label of the maximum value.
>
> If multiple values equal the maximum, the first row label with that
> value is returned.

```
row_with_max_DetectedSpeed = df.loc[df["DetectedSpeed"].idxmax()]

print(f"{row_with_max_DetectedSpeed.Area}\t{row_with_max_DetectedSpeed.Month}\t{row_with_max_DetectedSpeed.DetectedSpeed}")

Wendly  1   35
```

Comment: I had similar code to this but it didn't work, however yours did. Thanks a lot